# Is there a way to get the column indexes from VBA RefEdit for selected (multiple) ranges?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

In an UserForm I would like to select one or multiple ranges from a bigger data set via RefEdit control. The selected range(es) are the columns I want to perform the analysis with.

If I select for example multiple ranges I get following RefEdit value:

**data!$A$1:$A$2;data!$C$1:$F$2**

What I need would be instead an array with the values:

**1,3,4,5,6**

Is there a way to get the column number from the letters of this address (even the ones hidden by the statement "C:F" --> C,D,E,F ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might get unwieldy if you have large areas, but the example code below will extract unique column numbers from a range. The range in the example has multiple areas joined with `Union` and captures only the column numbers.

Notice that I included ranges in the `Union` that overlap in terms of columns, to guarantee the code works for that condition.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    With Sheet1
        Dim multi As Range
        Set multi = Union(.Range("A1:C3"), _
                          .Range("F7:H18"), _
                          .Range("C11:D14"))
        '--- Select is NOT necessary!
        '    only here to visualize the area
        multi.Select
    End With
    
    Debug.Print "Multi areas: " & multi.Address
    
    Dim columnsUsed As Collection
    Set columnsUsed = New Collection
    
    '--- adding a duplicate column number will cause an error
    '    the resulting Collection
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim item As Range
    For Each item In multi
        columnsUsed.Add item.Column, CStr(item.Column)
    Next item
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    '--- column numbers are not sorted in the collection
    '    but you can sort if required
    Dim columnNumber As Variant
    For Each columnNumber In columnsUsed
        Debug.Print columnNumber
    Next columnNumber
End Sub
```

Resulting output:

```
Multi areas: $A$1:$C$3,$F$7:$H$18,$C$11:$D$14
 1 
 2 
 3 
 6 
 7 
 8 
 4
```

Comment: Many thanks! When using it with RefEdit instead of union following line is needed:
multi = Range(Me.RefEdit1.Value)